# programmatically get bundles from field collection?

Tags: entities

Say I have the machine name of a given field collection. How can I programmatically get the names of the node bundles where one would find this field collection? This would be the same information you see on the `admin/structure/field-collections` page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
$bundle = db_query("SELECT bundle, entity_type FROM field_config_instance WHERE field_name = :field_name", array(':field_name' -> $field_name))->fetchAll();
```

If you know the enity_type then you can use [`field_info_instances()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7).

Comment: The query doesn't show me the relationship between bundles and field collections, but I can dig that info out of the giant array returned by `field_info_instances()`. Thanks!